# Foundation Button Groups plain html and ng-repeat different results

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, zurb-foundation-5

I upgrades my Foundation version from 5.3.3 to 5.5.2. Everything works great, expect some elements like button groups. Here is an example.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <ul class="button-group even-2">
      <li ng-repeat="i in [1, 2]">
        <a href="#" class="button tiny">{{i}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="button-group even-2">
      <li><a href="#" class="button tiny">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="button tiny">1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This two methods will create different results. The Angular `ng-repeat` directive will create an smaller result. How can this happen?

I created some reproduce able example. The first is the non working example.

Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/kauzbzby/1/
*Foundation 5.5.2*

The second example works as expected, but with an older Foundation version.

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/h5kqb4yv/1/
*Foundation 5.3.3*

The Angular version has not changed. Have someone an idea how to fix this?

Even examples without the `even-*` class will create different results

Cheers.

Comment: The problem lies in the `margin: 0 -2px;` on `.button-group.even-2 li` and `.button-group>li`. Using developers tools, removing these two rules makes everything the same width. However, it makes the non ng-repeat ones go on two lines... which I can't seem to find a fix for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/13k/gTm9S/

This is due to ng-repeat adding `li`s without spaces between them, where the manually created ones have a space due to the carriage return and tabs for alignment.

See here for your example working: http://jsfiddle.net/mk490brw/

```
<li><a href="#" class="button tiny">1</a></li><li><a href="#" class="button tiny">2</a></li><li><a href="#" class="button tiny">3</a></li><li><a href="#" class="button tiny">4</a></li><li><a href="#" class="button tiny">5</a></li><li><a href="#" class="button tiny">6</a></li><li><a href="#" class="button tiny">7</a></li>
```

Mushing all of the `li`s together in one line makes them the same width and spacing... even if it is a little unsightly to read.

Styles in 5.3.3 for button-group lis were

```
.button-group>li {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

Whereas 5.5.2 is:

```
.button-group.even-# li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  width: 14.28571%;
}
```

Again, the important part is the `inline-block`. Inline block makes any spaces between each element display as a space.

If you're curious as to *why* this was added, it appears that it was added to support button stacking. Here's the commit https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/d49b9a72b9d989f2c9c7156c6a30e510cc0c9df4

Comment: I created another example, where your fix wont work. I've to use an other margin value. Here you can play around: http://jsfiddle.net/zzc7zjkp/ So a global override won't work :(. It looks that angular and foundation won't play well together. I figured out that inline-block elements have problems with ng-repeat.

Comment: Edited answer. Turns out it's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: Thanks, this explains the Why, but the behavior is wrong. Why is it working in Foundation 5.3.3? The Code is exactly the same. The Twitter Bootstrap Framework don't have this problem. In my opinion there must be something wrong...